# Javascript RegEx to match URL's but exclude images

Tags: javascript, regex, image, hyperlink

I need to replace all text links in a string of HTML text by actual clickable links. Works fine with the following RegEx:

```
/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi
```

I then noticed it also replaces images and already formatted links. Figures I need to exclude links preceded by src" and > ... I searched a bit and read a lot on negative lookahead in many questions answered here. I tried this (added something right after the first /):

```
/(^(?!src="|>)\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi
```

But this doesn't match any link anymore. I tried several similar statements, without the ^, changing some brackets, etc etc, but simply nothing seems to work. I tried putting `.{0}` in between the part I added and \b, to make sure he would only look at stuff right in front of the url and not consider anything farther away.

Comment: It should not detect:
<img src="{link}">
Neither should it detect:
<a href="{link}">{link}</a>

So in short no link should be preceded by > or =" (taking both src=" and href=" at the same time here).

Comment: I like a good meaty regEx problem better than the next guy typically but I suspect innerHTMLing the text to a documentFragment and working with that would make it a lot easier to isolate text from html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** The discussion was getting long, so I decided to update the answer instead.

Trusting that your original regex works, I'm just going to refer to a simplified version through the rest of this answer:

```
/\b(https?|ftp|file)/gi
```

Now, you attempted this:

```
/^(?!src="|>)\b(https?|ftp|file)/gi
 ^
```

The main error here is marked by a caret: the caret.  That forces your regex to match from the beginning of the line, which is why it matched nothing.  Let's remove that and move on:

```
/(?!src="|>)\b(https?|ftp|file)/gi
```

The main error, this time, is in your conception of lookahead assertions.  As I explained in the comments, this assertion is redundant, because you are saying, "Match `http` or `https` or `ftp` or `file`, as long as none of these are `src="` or `>`."  It's almost so redundant that the sentence doesn't even make sense to us!  What you want, instead, is a *lookbehind* assertion:

```
/(?<!src="|>)\b(https?|ftp|file)/gi
   ^
```

Why?  Because you wish to find `src="` or `>` *behind* the string you potentially wish to match.  The problem?  JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind assertions.  So, I suggested an alternative.  Admittedly, it was flawed (although not the cause of the HTML breaking, as you brought up).  Here it is, fixed:

```
/(.[^>"]|[^=]")\b(https?|ftp|file)/gi
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is indeed a non-intuitive regex, and warrants explanation.  It splits our cases into two.  Say we have a two-character set.  If the set *doesn't* end in `>` or `"`, then we're not suspicious of it; we're good to go; match any URL that might follow.  However, if it *does* end in `>` or `"`, well, the only "forgivable" case is where the first character is not an `=`.  So you see, a bit of logic trickery here.

Now, as for why this might break your HTML.  Be sure to use JavaScript's `replace`, and substitute the first captured group back into the page!  If you simply substitute each match with nothingness, you end up "eating up" the two-character sets, which we only meant to investigate, not destroy.

```
html.replace(/(.[^>"]|[^=]")\b(https?|ftp|file)/gi,
             function(match, $1, offset, original) {
                 return $1;
             });
```

Comment: I thought I was using a look **ahead**, not a lookbehind? Or am I not?

Comment: Oh.  You are correct.  But my brain automatically corrected your error: putting your lookaround assertion where you did only would have worked if it were a _lookbehind_.  Currently you're saying, "The following string is not ``src="`` nor ``>``, but rather ``http``, ``ftp``, or ``file``," which is redundant since of course the latter list is never the former.  Anyway, that redundancy isn't what's causing the lack of matches.  It's your ``^``--take that out.

Comment: `/((?!="|>)\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi`

It now replaces everything, also images. I really don't see my mistake here. :-/

Comment: To be clear, you can't do what you're trying to do (at least, not simply) with a _lookahead_.  There is a "combinatoric brute-force" workaround that I keep posting on SO, which goes something like this.  ``([^s]|s([^r]|r([^c]|c([^=]|=[^"]))))\b(https?...``.

Comment: Let me give it another shot, with a simplified example. Here's what ``(?!=")ht`` says: "The next two characters are _not_ ``="``; the next two characters are ``ht``." (This is what I'm calling redundant. Of course ``="`` is never ``ht``!) Contrast this with what ``(?<!=")ht`` says: "The **previous** two characters are not ``="``; the **next** two characters are ``ht``." Basically, I think you are visualizing lookaheads wrong: what you need here is a lookbehind, which JavaScript doesn't provide, and so I've provided an alternative in my previous comment.

Comment: Here, your solution: ``([^=>]|=[^">])\b(http...``

Comment: I was trying to use lookahead where it wasn't needed? If I get this last reply of yours correctly, it excludes every link that is preceded with => OR =^ ? I'm a bit confused with one = in square brackets and another one outside of it. Blatantly copying what you wrote doesn't work anyways, it sort-of messes up the HTML page :p

Comment: Hey Kenneth.  Apologies for the delay.  I edited my solution to provide a more comprehensive answer.  Hope it helps.  Feel free to continue asking here.

Comment: OK, your regex works perfectly once I remove the . that's in it. It finds only the links that are not yet linkified or images as it should! I used the following method to replace:
`return htmlString.replace(regExHyperlinks,"<a href='$2' target='_blank'>$2</a>");`

The only thing that's going wrong now is that it cuts out the whichever char is standing right before the URL, as long as that's not a >. Other than that the script now works fine, so I'll mark this answer as the correct one. Thanks for the amazing help! Though any ideas why it cuts this char before the link?

Comment: Interesting; I'm not sure why the ``.`` would have mattered; but thanks for experimenting yourself.  As for the issue, you should be able to add ``$1``!  i.e. ``return htmlString.replace(regExHyperlinks,"$1<a href='$2' target='_blank'>$2</a>");``  But without seeing your new regex I can't be 100% confident.

Comment: Oh yea you were right! How silly of me! Should've figured that out myself! Works to perfection now. Thanks for this entire answer, you helped me a lot man! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to go home and haven't tested yet, but I'd feel more comfortable dealing with the easier task of isolating HTML you don't want out first.

1. Do a match to get an array of the stuff you don't want to deal with.
2. Rip it all out with a split.
3. Iterate the split array and replace URLs and then splice matched items back in
4. Join and return

The only assumption is that you don't end on an anchor or img tag in your text

```
function zipperParse(htmlText,matcher){
    var zipBackInArray = htmlText.match(matcher),
    workingArray = htmlText.split(matcher),
    i = workingArray.length;

    while(i--){
        buildAnchorTagIfURLPresent(workingArray[i]); //You got this one covered
        workingArray.splice(i,0,zipBackInArray.pop());
        //working backwards makes splice much easier to use here
    }
    return workingArray.join('');    
}

var toExclude = /<a[^>]*>[^>]*>|<img[^>]*>/g;
// is supposed to match all img and anchor pairs but not handling tags inside anchors yet

zipperParse(yourHtmlText,toExclude);
```

Comment: I have considered splitting and joining before but I considered that a too easy solution. My experience with RegEx is not that big and I have no doubt that this has now improved :-) Thanks for suggesting this solution!

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me... just change the Google Api KEY to exclude..=> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  i just put it in my functions.php theme of my wordpress.  The first thing is to see, how your google maps code appears on your site, and then it is to match it to what is replaced.

```
function remove_script_version( $src ) { 
$parts1 = explode( '?', $src );
$parts2 = str_replace('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=es&#038;v=3.31&#038;libraries=places&#038;key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&#038;ver=3.31', $parts1);
return $parts2[0]; }
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```